# Can "divisive" mean "intended to disrupt"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What is the meaning of "divisive" in this sentence:

> This makes it part of the tension and a participating force in divisive, military interventions in war zones.

Can it mean that both that:

a) The interventions are controversial?

b) The interventions aim to disrupt the political establishment in the country?

Comment: What this question about (Can it mean that both that)? Can you revise or amplify that interrogative sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Divisive* means "intended to *divide*" - if that division could cause disruption, then it would imply (but not mean) disruption.

It would most likely mean "the interventions are controversial" as "divisive" sort of implies something is making a whole divide into two separate sides.  Like a bunch of people forming alliances either for or against something after an event occurs.  But the second meaning is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I take it to mean that the military interventions unambiguously complete their aims, i.e. that there is no doubt in the outcome of the military intervention: success is completely `divided' from failure.